# Gradle include JavaFX for Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, javafx

For a current project I am in the need to set up a Gradle project on Heroku. Background is that I create a UI with JavaFX, but cannot test the functionalities directly because of firewall issues. So I changed the code so that I can test the functionalities using the Heroku cloud.
However I get a huge wave of compiler errors all referring to the missing Javafx library. I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40348237/6707985), but the answer provided is for Maven only.

Probably there are other ways (changing the JDK or something like that?) but the above was the only start I found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this OpenJFX buildpack to your app:

```
 $ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 https://github.com/jkutner/heroku-buildpack-javafx
```

This will download a [community distribution of JavaFX](https://chriswhocodes.com) and install it in your slug.

Comment: Hm, I did that, but still got the same errors. Do I have to include this buildpack in gradle somewhere as well? I tried [this](https://github.com/trautonen/heroku-buildpack-oracle-java) one as well, but no luck either (was for maven, but why don't give it a shot). Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I made a correction to my answer--you'll need the javafx buildpack to come before the gradle buildpack (so it's available during the gradle build).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.wildfly.swarm', name: 'javafx', version: '2017.4.0'
```

Comment: I do understand what this aims for (I think), but eventhough I added this I still get the compiler errors (package javafx.subPackage.subPackage.Class does not exists / cannot find symbol xy).

Comment: Maybe you need a different version of javafx?

Comment: Shouldn't they all contain the said packages? And I though the versions were downwards compatible... I tried the one out that is in the linked question, but that did not work either.